# Flutter Kotlin Get Data from Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I'm trying to have my own bluetooth kotlin implementation, but am running into a problem.

I am starting a broadcast receiver for scanning bluetooth devices by following the kotlin tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#kotlin).

The problem is that when i try to add each discovered device to a main activity wide mutable list from the broadcast receiver so that i can send the list to the flutter side, i always get a null.

Since im new to kotlin and android i cant really understand where exactly im going wrong, and which concepts do i need to understand to do what i need to do.

**Kotlin MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

    private val CHANNEL = "bluetooth.channel"
     var deviceList: MutableList<BluetoothDevice>?=null;

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {

        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->

            when (call.method) {
                "getBlue" -> bluetoothWrapper(result)
                "discoverBlue" -> discoverDevices(deviceList,result)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun bluetoothWrapper(result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        val defaultAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
        checkAdapter(result, defaultAdapter);
        enableAdapter(defaultAdapter!!);
    }


    private fun checkAdapter(result: MethodChannel.Result, defaultAdapter: BluetoothAdapter?) {   // check if adapter exists
        if (defaultAdapter == null) {
            result.error("Bluetooth adapter doesn't exist on this device", null, null)
        } else {
            result.success("bluetooth adapter exists on device")
        }


    }

    // check if adapter is enabled if it exists, enable it if it isnt

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun enableAdapter(bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter) {
        val requestEnableBt = 1;
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {
            val enableIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, requestEnableBt)
        }
    }

    // register broadcast receiver in order to discover available devices

    private fun discoverDevices(deviceList: MutableList<BluetoothDevice>?, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        val filter = IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)

        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        result.success(deviceList)
    }
    private val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            when (intent.action) {
                BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND -> {
                    val device: BluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                    deviceList?.add(device)

                    println("device found has selected parameters inside the broadcast receivver function $device")
                }
                "" -> println("broadcast receiver intent.action has no attribute")
                null -> println("broadcast receiver intent.action was null")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Flutter Main.Dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const platform = const MethodChannel('bluetooth.channel');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Bluetooth Native'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.blue[500],
                onPressed: () {
                  printMethod();
                },
                child: Text('connect to Devices'),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.blue[500],
                onPressed: () {
                  discoverBlue();
                },
                child: Text('Discover devices'),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void printMethod() async {
    String value;
    try {
      value = await platform.invokeMethod("getBlue");
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    print('printing from dart: $value');
  }

  void discoverBlue() async {
    Future<List> list;
    list = platform.invokeListMethod("discoverBlue", list);
    list.then((val) {
      print("got values from kotlin $val");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find what went wrong? Could you share an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have not triggered to start the discovery process.
you need to do

```
        val myAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        myAdapter.startDiscovery();
```

also since it is async task in kotlin.
return the result in

```
BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED
```

So your MainActivity.kt will be

```
package com.example.testapp

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Activity
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant


class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

    private val CHANNEL = "bluetooth.channel"
    var deviceList: MutableList<BluetoothDevice>? = null;

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {

        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->

            when (call.method) {
                "getBlue" -> bluetoothWrapper(result)
                "discoverBlue" -> discoverDevices(deviceList, result)
                "allPaired" -> getConnectedDevices(result)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getConnectedDevices(result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        val mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
        val pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices

        val s: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
        for (bt in pairedDevices) s.add(bt.name)
        result.success(s);
    }

    private fun bluetoothWrapper(result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        val defaultAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
        checkAdapter(result, defaultAdapter);
        enableAdapter(defaultAdapter!!);
    }


    private fun checkAdapter(result: MethodChannel.Result, defaultAdapter: BluetoothAdapter?) {   // check if adapter exists
        if (defaultAdapter == null) {
            result.error("Bluetooth adapter doesn't exist on this device", null, null)
        } else {
            result.success("bluetooth adapter exists on device")
        }


    }

    // check if adapter is enabled if it exists, enable it if it isnt

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun enableAdapter(bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter) {
        val requestEnableBt = 1;
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {
            val enableIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, requestEnableBt)
        }
    }

    // register broadcast receiver in order to discover available devices

    private fun discoverDevices(deviceList: MutableList<BluetoothDevice>?, result: MethodChannel.Result) {

        val myAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        myAdapter.startDiscovery();

        val filter = IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
        val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                when (intent.action) {
                    BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND -> {
                        val device: BluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                        deviceList?.add(device)
                        println("device found has selected parameters inside the broadcast receivver function $device")
                    }
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED -> {
                        result.success(deviceList)
                    }
                    "" -> println("broadcast receiver intent.action has no attribute")
                    null -> println("broadcast receiver intent.action was null")
                }
            }
        }
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
    }


}
```

and main.dart will be

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const platform = const MethodChannel('bluetooth.channel');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Bluetooth Native'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.blue[500],
              onPressed: () {
                printMethod();
              },
              child: Text('connect to Devices'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.blue[500],
              onPressed: () {
                discoverBlue();
              },
              child: Text('Discover devices'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.blue[500],
              onPressed: () {
                getAllPaired();
              },
              child: Text('All paired devices'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void printMethod() async {
    String value;
    try {
      value = await platform.invokeMethod("getBlue");
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    print('printing from dart: $value');
  }

  void discoverBlue() async {
    Future<List> list;
    list = platform.invokeListMethod("discoverBlue", list);
    list.then((val) {
      print("got values from kotlin $val");
    });
  }

  void getAllPaired() async {
    var value = await platform.invokeListMethod("allPaired");
    print(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't deliver devices caught in the onReceive method to the flutter end. Any idea on what could be wrong?